# My Android game cancelled the payment callback when returning from the background after payment,while another game successfully completed the payment

Tags: android, google-pay

Switching to the background card page and then returning to the foreground can be a successful payment, but switching directly to the background cancels the payment.

How to handle this situation so that the payment can still be completed after switching to the background after payment?